# How to add Outlook.TaskItems to already existing Outlook.Items?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, task

I've looked all over the internet and could not find an answer for this one...

Basically, what I want to do is to retrieve all the TaskItems from all the Tasks folders and put them into one single Outlook.Items list.
I know how to look at all the folders and how to retrieve the tasks from these folders, but i don't know how to put together all the tasks I retrieve.

So,
I have some Outlook.Items that i get from a folder like this:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder outlookTasksFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
        Outlook.Items outItems = outlookTasksFolder.Items;
```

Then, I'd like to add a TaskItem to outItems.

Anyone knows how to do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

there is an Add method on the Items collection 
outItems.Add(TaskItem) will do the trick.

76mel

Answer (score 0):

As 76mel said create a new folder and use the Items.Add method to add all of the tasks into it.